# Google engine app + email API : user from different domain not trusted?

Tags: java, security, google-app-engine, google-api-java-client

We are running GAE app on **.com** domain where most of customer`s users does have google accounts. Our GAE app sends email on behalf of user sometimes.

We found it's not possible to send email for our **.co.uk** users (app sends email silently but it`s never delivered...).

Naturally this happens because .com domain does have DKIM switched on in Google Apps > Advanced tools > DKIM.

Is there any other way how to send emails through google email API for all our users (from various domains) ? Users are authorized by google OAuth2 mechanism.